# List all files in an iCloud folder

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

I want to search a folder that exists in my iCloud Drive for files. How can I get the paths of all files inside an iCloud folder on an iOS device or on Mac (via Catalyst)?

Comment: What have you tried? What part of it isn't working? Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check iCloud > iCloud Documents in Xcode project Signing & Capabilities.
2. Then we need the user to allow access to the Folder. Follow the directions in the [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories). It shows how to ask for permission to access a folder by selecting it via the `UIDocumentPickerViewController` . It also shows how to list all files in that iCloud folder (even files outside the app’s container) and save it for future access.